# How to use Named Credentials in a Basic Auth callout with API key?

Tags: rest-api, callout, httprequest, namedcredentials, unauthorized-endpoint

This initial code works perfectly to do a Callout with UN, PW and API key in Custom Settings.
But this is less secure and so I want to move teh UN & PW to Named Credentials.
but it fails.

This Endpoint is a Boomi endpoint:
**Here is the working Code:**

```
@future(Callout=True)
public static void sendDataToBoomi(String bodyStr){
    My_Creds__c myCreds = My_Creds__c.getOrgDefaults();
    String endPoint = 'https://ourdomain.boomi.cloud:portNum/standardPath/myService';
    String authString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode( Blob.valueOf(myCreds.Boomi_Username__c + ':' + myCreds.Boomi_Password__c));

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'BASIC '+ authString);
    request.setEndpoint(endPoint);
    request.setBody(bodyStr);
    request.setHeader('X-API-KEY', myCreds.Boomi_API_Key__c);
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    }
}
Response: **200**
```

**If I comment this line out** : //request.setHeader('X-API-KEY', myCreds.Boomi_API_Key__c);

I get an expected failure, because the API key is missing.

Response:  **"message" : "Unauthorized", "http_status_code" : 401**

**However this code does not work:**

It uses the documented approach, expect that the API Keys are not in the documentation of course.

```
@future(Callout=True)
public static void sendDataToBoomi(String bodyStr){
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setBody(bodyStr);
    request.setEndpoint('callout:BoomiRESTfulAPI/myService');
    request.setHeader('X-API-KEY', myCreds.Boomi_API_Key__c);
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
}
response: **"message" : "invalid credential", "http_status_code" : 401**
```

**If I comment this line out** : //request.setHeader('X-API-KEY', myCreds.Boomi_API_Key__c);

I get failure, much like the first expected failure when the Key is removed.

Response:  **"message" : "Unauthorized", "http_status_code" : 401**

I have seen posts that use $Credentials, but the examples given do not make sense when the merge field does not reference the specific Named Credential.
Also if my API Key is stored in the named Credential.PW then I cannot see how I can use a Password to Auth???

**Here is my Named Credentials Setup**
[image]

Comment: If Boomi requires username + password AND API key, then Named Cred is a half-measure: it can only do one of those. Boomi API [doc](https://help.boomi.com/bundle/integration/page/int-AtomSphere_API_Tokens_page.html) says that _As an alternative to user name and password credentials, API tokens are a form of authentication that users can generate and use to successfully authenticate calls to the AtomSphere API and AtomSphere Partner API_ but perhaps you're calling some other API.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not across the boomi build, I am only being told the interface. But thank you, good to know.

Comment: You are right, you don't need to make use of merge fields (and should untick the "Allow Merge Fields..." options). Your approach is correct. I suspect a small slip in the code. (E.g. your second example has "gv" as a static var - is it properly initialized?) You can compare the two requests header-by-header: Configure `"http://httpbin.org/headers"` as your endpoint of a test Named Credential (and as a Remote Site in SF's Setup), change the method to GET and System-debug the response body. The Named Credential setup must produce the same headers as the Custom Setting setup.

Comment: @felix, Thank you great recommendation, I will build a custom endpoint and see what is being sent.
FYI my gv variable was just a transaltion issue to this platform, please ignore that my mistake to let it come into SE. gv in the original code is not causing an issue it is correctly initialized :)

Thanks Again!