# Making an API Callout with Amazon Cognito client credentials authorization

Tags: oauth2, authentication, namedcredentials

I want to call an API that is authenticated with Amazon Cognito using a client credentials auth flow. I have been provided the client key and client secret. My set up uses SF **Auth. Providers** and **Named Credentials** to perform authentication. Some other SF Stackexchange posts I am referencing include [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366579/how-to-use-named-credentials-in-a-basic-auth-callout-with-api-key), [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/329816/manage-client-id-and-client-secret), and [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225121/named-credentials-and-support-for-the-oauth2-client-credentials-grant-type-and-a?noredirect=1&lq=1). However I am running into an error that results in the `Authentication Status` of the Named Credential is stuck as `Pending`.

[image: Auth. Provider setup]

[image: Named Credentials setup]

Upon saving the Named Credential, the auth flow is immediately initialized. This takes me to an error screen with a redirect mismatch error, shown below.

[image: Cognito sign in redirect mismatch error]

Prior to setting this up in SF, I had validated the authentication flow by using `curl` commands to get the access token and make the API callout with the access token. I have searched up issues related to Cognito redirect_mismatch errors but applying similar changes have not been fruitful. Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:**

Per Callum's answer below, I edited my Cognito user pool app client settings to add in the callback and sign out URLs supplied by SF. These can be found in the **Auth. Provider Detail** section at the bottom. This did indeed lead me to get past the redirect mismatch error.

However I now encounter the following error.

> Problem Logging In
>
> We can’t log you in because of an authentication error. For help, contact your Salesforce administrator.

Seems like this may be on my SF account side of things.

Comment: Out of the box, OpenID Connect auth provider only supports authorization code grant flow. To use client credentials, you have to write Apex code.

Answer (score 0):

If this has been working previously using Curl, the error is likely to be caused by the setup of the Callback and/or Sign Out URL settings within Cognito. If these haven't been updated to reference your Salesforce instance then you'll get these redirect errors.

It looks like the author of this post (although Android app related) was having the same issues and updating these URLs solved the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50936774/amazon-cognito-how-to-stop-getting-redirect-mismatch-error-when-redirecting-f

Answer (score 0):

Callum's answer was correct in terms of handling the redirect mismatch error, but that error itself was a red herring in trying to set up the client credential auth flow between SF and Cognito. As identigral called out in the comments, this is not available with out-of-the-box SF resources.

The method I found and applied successfully was created by Mikkel Flindt ([blog post](https://lekkimworld.com/2021/05/07/custom-salesforce-auth-provider-for-microsoft-azure-client_credentials-flow/) / [github repo](https://github.com/lekkimworld/salesforce-azure-clientcredentials-authprovider)), who solves the problem for client credential auth flow between SF and Microsoft Azure. He even has a video in his Github readme showing his process.

I am not a SF power user so I didn't do everything in his video, e.g. making a scratch org. I just created an Apex class with mostly the same code as his `Azure_ClientCredentials_AuthProvider` class and then manually created mostly the same **Custom Metadata**, **Auth. Provider**, and **Named Credential** resources.
Very few changes are needed to achieve the same thing with Cognito, which I'll document here.

1. Instead of a `Tenant_ID` field, have a `UserPool_Name` field
2. Additionally, have a `Region` field
3. Reconfigure the token endpoint string to be `final String tokenEndpoint = 'https://' + userPoolName + '.auth.' + region + '.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token';` (Note: this is the default domain that is used for Cognito user pools. If you use your own domain, obviously you would have to change that.)
4. Change all instances of MicrsoftAzure or Azure to Cognito, of course.
5. I did *not* change the `Callback_URL` field in the custom metadata or anything related to callback URL in the Apex code, but I also found that you do *not* need to have a callback URL specified for the Cognito user pool. It works if you leave it blank.

Huge kudos to Mikkel Flindt, thanks to the users who helped point in the right direction in this question thread, and I hope this helps anyone in the future who is struggling with Cognito or with client credential auth flow.